# WordPress AJAX Form With Array Elements

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress, form-data

To be 100% clear, I'm not asking how to use ajax with WordPress... I already know how to do that.

My issue is that I have form elements with array names that aren't parsing the way I need them to into the $_POST variable. I'm getting the javascript FormData syntax rather than the PHP syntax.

Example...

the HTML...

```
<form id="registerForm">
    <input name="borrower[0][first_name]">
    <input name="borrower[0][last_name]">
    <input name="borrower[1][first_name]">
    <input name="borrower[1][last_name]">
    <button>Submit</button>
</form>
```

the JS...

```
$('#registerForm').submit(function() {
    var data = $(this).serializeArray();
    // also tried data = new FormData(document.getElementById('registerForm'));
    $.ajax(
        url: ...,
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {
            action: 'some_wp_action',
            formData: data
        },
        success: function(response) {
            console.log(response);
        }
    );
})
```

the PHP...

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_some_wp_action', 'some_wp_action' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_some_wp_action', 'some_wp_action' );

function some_wp_action() {
    exit(json_encode($_POST['formData']));
}
```

the output...

```
[
    {"name":"borrower[0][first_name]","value":"John"}
    {"name":"borrower[0][last_name]","value":"Doe"}
    {"name":"borrower[1][first_name]","value":"Jane"}
    {"name":"borrower[0][last_name]","value":"Doe"}
]
```

I need the output to be an associative array like it would be if you just posted the form data naturally...

```
[
    {"borrower":[
        {"first_name":"John","last_name":"Doe"},
        {"first_name":"Jane","last_name":"Doe"}
    ]}
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK so I think the answer is here: [Convert form data to JavaScript object with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1184624/convert-form-data-to-javascript-object-with-jquery#answer-1186309)

You'll want to use the `serializeObject` function. Here's a [simple fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5x9hLj8v/).

So your js would probably come out looking something like this:

```
$('#registerForm').submit(function() {
    var data = $(this).serializeObject();
    $.ajax({
        url: "submit.php",
        data: {
            action: 'some_wp_action',
            user: data
        },
        success: function(response) {
            $("#msg").html(response);
        }
    });
    return false;
})

$.fn.serializeObject = function()
{
    var o = {};
    var a = this.serializeArray();
    $.each(a, function() {
        if (o[this.name] !== undefined) {
            if (!o[this.name].push) {
                o[this.name] = [o[this.name]];
            }
            o[this.name].push(this.value || '');
        } else {
            o[this.name] = this.value || '';
        }
    });
    return o;
};
```

It's also unclear from the example you posted why you need to explicitly state the `user[0]` location for only one user anyway, so I simplified it for this example as such:

```
<form action="submit.php" id="registerForm" onsubmit="return false">
    <input name="username">
    <input name="email">
    <input type="password" name="pw">
    <input type="password" name="pw_confirm">
    <button>Submit</button>
</form>
```

this produced the following output:

```
{"action":"some_wp_action","user":{"username":"asdf","email":"fdsa","pw":"pasasdf","pw_confirm":"pasfdsa"}}
```

Comment: In the use case specified the array input may not be necessary however there are use cases that would require it which is why I need it. Perhaps I should have used a better example such as borrower[0][first_name] and borrower[1][first_name] which is useful for joint applicants in a loan

Comment: the concept should be the same, have you tried using the `serializeObject` function?

Comment: It does not work. It returns... `{"borrower[0":"first_name":"John","last_name":"Doe"}}`

Comment: This is partially the answer. I had to use `$(this).serializeObject()`, append to it with `data.action = 'some_wp_action'` and then `data: data` in the ajax call